# Вывести данные за последние 30 минут без будущего времени

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Мне нужно вывести данные из таблицы mysql за последние 30 минут от нынешнего времени, но выводятся и данные с будущим датой и временем, как избавиться от этой будущей даты?

пользуюсь запросом в таблице MYSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM kv_xml WHERE DATETIME > NOW() - INTERVAL 1000  MINUTE;
```

Comment: `and datetime <= now()` или в чём сложность? Ну и 1000  MINUTE - это явно не 30.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так добавь

```
and datetime <= now()
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WHERE DATETIME BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1000 MINUTE AND NOW()
```